# MongoDB query: How do I find an object that matches two fields (when updating another field)?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express

I am trying to update the 'expelled' field to true, when students' ages are 13, and 'strikes' count is 3 - in the school with an ID of 101.

To rephrase it, how do I update a value in an object that is found based on a query of two matching criteria within the object being updates. An illustration of the collection is below.

```js
collection: [
  { schoolID: 101,
    students: [
      { 
        name: "Jim",
        age: 13,
        strikes: 3,
        expelled: false
      },
      { 
        name: "Zack",
        age: 13,
        strikes: 0,
        expelled: false
      },
      { 
        name: "Sarah",
        age: 11,
        strikes: 1,
        expelled: false
      }
    ]
  },
  { schoolID: 102,
    students: [...]
  }
}
```

Here is my current attempt which isn't working, despite me getting this from some other article on here. But it wasn't tailored to what I need specifically.

```js
const expelStudents = collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {"schoolID": 101, "students.age": 13, "students.strikes": 3},
  {"$set": {
    "students.$.expelled": true
    }}
  );
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated and credited. Thanks.

Comment: What response are you getting so far? What the result of your query?

Comment: No response, it is running, but MongoDB is not updating it.

Comment: First use `await collection.findOne({"schoolID": 101, "students.age": 13, "students.strikes": 3})` and show us the result object. I want to see what you get back.